# This sentence is a little confusing

Tags: discourse-context

This is from "Artificial Intelligence For Dummies"

> Algorithms are all about finding solutions, and the speedier and
> easier, the better. Algorithms have become hard-coded in the
> intelligence of humans who devised them, and any machine operating on
> algorithms cannot but reflect the intelligence embedded into such
> algorithmic procedures.

Considering [the meaning of 'hard-code'](https://www.google.com/search?q=hard-coded%20meaning&oq=h&aqs=chrome.1.69i59l2j69i57j69i60l5.3403j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which means 'fix (data or parameters) in a program in such a way that they cannot be altered without modifying the program' and the phrase in the quote 'the intelligence embedded into...', I think the quote should be rephrased like this :

> Algorithms are all about finding solutions, and the speedier and
> easier, the better. **The intelligence of humans who devised algorithms has
> become hard-coded in them**, and any machine operating on
> algorithms cannot but reflect the intelligence embedded into such
> algorithmic procedures.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you are wrong, kind of.

The original sentence is confusing:

> Algorithms have become hard-coded in the intelligence of humans who devised them

because, when reading the first part of the sentence, it appears that the *concept* of algorithms is what has become hard-coded, but by the end it is clear that the author is trying to indicate that when a human devises an algorithm, that algorithm becomes hard-coded in their intelligence, presumably because they have thought about it so much.

Your sentence:

> The intelligence of humans who devised algorithms has become hard-coded in them

suggests that it is the intelligence, not the algorithm, which is embedded.  This does not match the meaning of the original sentence.

The next clause:

> any machine operating on algorithms cannot but reflect the intelligence embedded into such algorithmic procedures

implies that when an algorithm is hard-coded into a machine, it is endowed with a rudiment of the intelligence of the human who designed it.  The connection to the preceding sentence is dubious, but I guess the writer was trying to say that learning algorithms makes both humans and machines more intelligent.

Language aside, this seems to be getting at one of the core ideas in *Gödel, Escher, Bach* by Douglas R. Hofstadter—that algorithms which comprehend themselves bestow some form of consciousness to their executors.

Comment: Thank you very much.